# How do validators pass in custom data sets that is available for all applications to easily use?

Tags: pallet, validator, oracles

Suppose we want to create a chain which has a native oracle "module" - is it possible to customize the validators to provide the information, or do we develop a pallet for this?

In either case, we need some kind of affirmative data on-chain that provides data for applications to easily use.

Would be super grateful if someone pointed me to the right direction here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally you will need `ocw` to achieve that and with `sp_io::offchain::is_validator()` to feed oracle only by validators.

Just take `im-online` for reference

Comment: Thanks! And how will the data be passed to the other oracles for consensus gathering?